# Json-schema allow a preset of objects that are specified elsewhere

Tags: jsonschema

I want to define a json-schema where one property of an object (`fruit`) is selected from a list of objects. These objects themselves are all defined by the schema `fruit`. What is a good way to do it?

While I can easily specify the allowed objects as an enum, I also want to validate that the ones specified there are in fact a `fruit`.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "description": "this is my favorite fruit",
    "enum": [
        {
            "name": "apple",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "color": "yellow"
        },
        {
            "name": "oops, that's not a fruit",
            "taste": "fantastic"
        }
    ],
    "$defs": {
        "fruit": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "color": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "required": [
                "name",
                "color"
            ],
            "unevaluatedProperties": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`enum` validates exact JSON.  It's really just a shorthand for a series of `const`s inside an `anyOf`.

```json
{
  "enum": [
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "name": "banana",
      "color": "yellow"
    },
    {
      "name": "oops, that's not a fruit",
      "taste": "fantastic"
    }
  ]
}
```

is equivalent to

```json
{
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "const": {
        "name": "apple",
        "color": "red"
      }
    },
    {
      "const": {
        "name": "banana",
        "color": "yellow"
      }
    },
    {
      "const": {
        "name": "oops, that's not a fruit",
        "taste": "fantastic"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any additional validation on these values would be redundant.  Really, you just want to be careful when building your schema.

---

The only case that I can see where you might want additional validation on the items in an `enum` (like you're asking) would be when you're not *writing* the schema, but iteratively *generating* it by adding acceptable values in a loop somewhere in code, and you want to ensure that each of those values are correct.

If that's the case, trying to validate the items after they've been added to the schema is too late.  You want to validate each item *before* you add it.

```
for each item in items
    result = item_schema.validate(item)
    if result.valid
       schema.enum.add(item)
```

or something along those lines.

Here `item_schema` is a separate schema that defines what it means to be a fruit.